# Copying from one binary tree to another

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying to write various methods to create binary trees one of which is a copy method from an existing binary tree

Create tree from vector

```
binary_tree::binary_tree(const std::vector<int> &values)
{
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    insert(values[i]);
}
}
```

Inserting nodes

```
void insertnode(node **tree, int value)
{
if (*tree == nullptr)
{
    *tree = new node;
    (*tree)->data = value;
    (*tree)->left = nullptr;
    (*tree)->right = nullptr;
}
else
    if(value < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insertnode(&(*tree)->left, value);
    }
    else if(value > (*tree)->data)
    {
        insertnode(&(*tree)->right, value);
    }
    else 
        return;
}


void binary_tree::insert(int value)
{
insertnode(&tree, value);
}
```

Copying method

```
binary_tree::binary_tree(const binary_tree &rhs)
{   
copyTree(tree2, tree);
}

void copyTree(node *& tree2, node *& tree)
{
if(tree == NULL)
{
    tree2 = NULL;
}
else
{
    tree2 = new node;
    tree2->data = tree->data;

    copyTree(tree2->left, tree->left);
    //cout << tree2->data << " ";
    copyTree(tree2->right, tree->right);
}
}
```

Printing method

```
std::string binary_tree::inorder() const
{

inorderof(tree);
std::string back2 = back.substr(0, back.length()-1);    
back = "";

return std::string(back2);

void inorderof(node *tree)                              
{
    if(tree != nullptr)
    {
        inorderof(tree->left);  
        back += to_string(tree->data);  
        back += " ";
        inorderof(tree->right);

    }
}
```

Main

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

tree = new binary_tree(vector<int>{10, 5, 12, 15, 8});
tree->inorder();

binary_tree *tree2 = new binary_tree(*tree);
tree2->inorder();
}
```

My issue is that I have to copy the initial tree - which builds and prints perfectly fine - and copy it using the

```
 binary_tree::binary_tree(const binary_tree &rhs)
```

method, however I am getting some unresolved external error when the tree gets copied.

I have tried to copy the tree without using the above method which works, however having to pass the initial binary tree through as an argument into this method stumps me and I don't know where to go from there. I have to use this exact method declaration as part of an assignment otherwise I wouldn't do it this way!

error message:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall
>   binary_tree::copyTree(struct node * &,struct node * &)"
>   (?copyTree@binary_tree@@QAEXAAPAUnode@@0@Z) referenced in function
>   "public: __thiscall binary_tree::binary_tree(class binary_tree const
>   &)" (??0binary_tree@@QAE@ABV0@@Z)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you possibly show the error message that you are getting? (Also I believe your text cut off with `I have tried to`... )

Comment: Sorry I've been working on this all day and I pressed send by mistake, I updated it now! Thanks for any help you can give me

Comment: is copyTree declared (in the header) as member of binary_tree? Because it's implemented (in the .cpp file, as you presented) as a free function.

Comment: it is declared in the header yes however copyTree doesn't even get called as the binary_tree(const binary_tree &rhs) method errors

Comment: Can you post your header? Here you have a linking error that suggests you should define a void binary_tree::copyTree function in the cpp instead of just void copyTree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not visible in the code you posted, but I'm fairly sure that your header contains something like:

```
class binary_tree {
 ...
 void copyTree(node *& tree2, node *& tree);
 ...
}
```

and in your source file you have:

```
void copyTree(node *& tree2, node *& tree)
{
if(tree == NULL)
{
    tree2 = NULL;
}
else
{
    tree2 = new node;
    tree2->data = tree->data;

    copyTree(tree2->left, tree->left);
    //cout << tree2->data << " ";
    copyTree(tree2->right, tree->right);
}
}
```

You can fix this either by changing signature in source file to:

```
void binary_tree::copyTree(node *& tree2, node *& tree) {...}
```

or by removing it from header (if you choose this path, make sure that `copyTree` is defined (or at least declared) in the source before its usage (`binary_tree(const binary_tree &rhs)` ).

Comment: Thanks alot this fixed it!